# Why clearInterval not clearing the setInterval timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have creating an simple Timer service. In the timer service, I am monitoring the user for each minute.

While page load, have set 3 minutes to get an alert to logout and before 1 minute which means 2 minutes  to get a bootstrap warning while click  the proceed button,it will clear the current intervals and again assign 3 minutes, else, get an warning alert to logout after 3 minutes.

For the first time its working fine, while clicking the proceed button, its not reassign the value for the user. For the 3rd minute itself, its showing the logout.

Where is wrong in the piece of code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@4.0.0-alpha.4" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="TimerService()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <h1 id="title">Javascript timer problem</h1>
    <div id="modeldialog"></div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <label class="session-expiration">
              <span>Session Expiration</span>
              <img src="~/Images/Warning_Alert_Icon_26.png" />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="session-message">
              <p class="time-message">your Session will expire in                                  <i id="timer" class="fa fa-clock-o">
                  <span class="expire">Minutes </span>
                </i>

.click proceed to stay Login.</p>
              <p class="time-message">
                <b>Click Proceed to stay Login.</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="LogOut()">Logout</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="proceed()">Proceed</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function proceed()
 {
 $("#myModal").toggle();
 TimerService();
 }

function load(){
  alert(" if click proceed , timer service extended another 3 minutes else logout after 3 ");
   $("#myModal").modal();

  }

 function TimerService()
   {
   alert("TimerService");
    var timer = false;
    clearInterval(timer); 
    if (timer == false) {
        var lastDigestRun = new Date();   
           lastDigestRun = Date.now();
            var s = lastDigestRun + 3 * 60 * 1000;
            // for reference
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  new Date(s);
            console.info("Your logout time +" + new Date(s));

               timer=setInterval(function () {                   
                  var now = Date.now();
                   var displaytime = now - lastDigestRun > 2 * 60 * 1000;

                    if (now - lastDigestRun > 2 * 60 * 1000) {                      
                       load();
                       }

                      if (now - lastDigestRun > 3 * 60 * 1000) {
                        alert("logout");

                        }     
                }, 60 * 1000);

        }
}
```

Plunker Demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qwNJF648LIvUUNT3IMkc?p=preview

Comment: You are clearing before creating `setInterval()`

Comment: `clearInterval` only clears `setInterval` timers not `setTimeout` ones.

Comment: @Jyothi Babu Araja then where i have to clear because for the first time , need to run the timer on load , after click proceed, again need to reassign the timer

Comment: @Bergi: that's not true actually: try `var t = setTimeout("alert(666)", 500);clearInterval(t);` if you don't see an alert, they are interchangeable. if you do, please tell us the browser that's odd.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja still  not able to clear  the interval something goes wrong Pls look here https://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [window.clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) on the `timer` variable to cancel the timeout.

For example, in your `TimerService()`

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer)
}
```

and use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`. It's more appropriate to your context. If you want to remove keep using `setInterval()`, update the code above with `clearInterval()` instead of `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: sorry i have updated my Question, i have used clear interval but its not clearing something went wrong in the piece of code.

Comment: Something went wrong here still not able to clear if interest look here github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession –

Answer (score 0):

you have the following bit of code:

```
var timer = false;
clearInterval(timer);
if (timer == false){
```

For obvious reasons, this is always going to evaluate as true. Furthermore, clearInteval will do nothing, as it is called on false

Comment: Something went wrong here not able to clear if interest look here https://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession